# Community Nickname and Alias

Tags: user-management

I know that Community Nickname and Alias are system generated fields and they automatically take values once user record is created.

However, we have a feed coming from external application containing details of user record. Community Nickname and Alias are also 2 fields coming from the system to Salesforce.

My question is : Can these fields be populated with values from External System into Salesforce or will Salesforce autopopulate these values as per its algorithm and override the values mentioned by External System feed?

Please advise.

Comment: Hi, were you able to do this? I'm looking for a solution to this as well. Thanks!

Comment: yes, i followed the answers given and it worked for me.

Answer (score 5):

You should be able to populate the fields from an external system without a problem.

However, there's one thing to keep in mind, the community nickname is a unique name used on the salesforce community.

- Alias <= 8 chars
- Community nickname <= 40 chars

Comment: Community nicknames only need to be unique for your org, not across all orgs.

Comment: edited my answer.

Answer (score 3):

You can surely use .Do remember few things

1)Alias cannot exceed 8 chararcters

2)Community nickname cannot extend 40 characters

3)Community nickname is unique field .Hence duplicate will throw execptions and user wont be created

https://login.salesforce.com/help/doc/en/user_fields.htm